# Why is it direct commented Encoded string not converting to Arabic?

Tags: ios, utf-8, arabic, latin1

```
NSString * string  = @"االْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ";
    const char *c = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:c   encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"%@",newString);


//    NSString * staticEncodedString = @"Ø§ÙÙØ­ÙÙ ÙØ¯Ù ÙÙÙÙÙÙÙ Ø±ÙØ¨ÙÙ Ø§ÙÙØ¹ÙØ§ÙÙÙ ÙÙÙÙ";
    const char *cvvv = [newString cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    NSString *newStringV = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:cvvv  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"%@",newStringV);
```

Why is it direct commented Encoded string not converting to Arabic?
When i hardcode the Arabic it encodes and then decodes correctly, but why can't static encoded string not readable in arabic?

Thanks for your reply Jake. Yes I loose data while decoding the "staticEncodedString".But All I want is to decode the following string back to Arabic.

```
 NSString * staticEncodedString = @"Ø§ÙÙØ­ÙÙ ÙØ¯Ù ÙÙÙÙÙÙÙ Ø±ÙØ¨ÙÙ Ø§ÙÙØ¹ÙØ§ÙÙÙ ÙÙÙÙ";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encode is in ANSI i think change it to UTF-8 from any tool.
Use Notepad++ to apply for example and then you can use encode it within sqlite or ios.

Answer (score 1):

Latin1 can not represent the Arabic characters, so you can not encode that string to Latin1. Arabic belongs to the Latin4 character set. The method cStringUsingEncoding will return null if the string cannot losslessly be encoded to the specified encoding.

Why would you want to encode an arabic string to LatinX? UTF-8 will most likely be the best representation since it uses only standard characters and a straightforward approach with no headaches. It may take a bit more bytes than Latin4, but in most cases it will be worth it.

Converting to Latin1 will make you lose your text.